# Programming Linux network driver to support turning off TCP checksum offload

Tags: linux, tcp, linux-device-driver

I am programming a linux networking driver. It is almost done. When I ping between 2 PCs, everything is perfect. And then I try to use some TCP/UDP protocols, the receiver never replies. I used wireshark to see what happens there, and I found all the TCP packets have incorrect checksum. It is said the wrong checksum is caused by TCP checksum offload. I tried to turn it off with ethtool. When I use `sudo ethtool -K uwn0 tx off`, it replies me

```
Cannot get device rx-checksumming settings: Operation not supported
Cannot get device tx-checksumming settings: Operation not supported
Cannot get device scatter-gather settings: Operation not supported
Cannot get device tcp-segmentation-offload settings: Operation not supported
Cannot get device udp-fragmentation-offload settings: Operation not supported
Cannot get device generic-segmentation-offload settings: Operation not supported
Cannot get device generic-receive-offload settings: Operation not supported
Cannot get device flags: Operation not supported
```

Is there a way to make my driver support tcp checksum offload? Or just compute checksum in software? 
Thanks

Comment: This is a good question but should be over at http://serverfault.com/

Comment: @JamesC No, it belongs here, because it's about *writing the network device driver* rather than how to configure an existing driver.

Answer (score 1):

When setting up your device's interface within your driver, you should unset the flag `NETIF_F_HW_CSUM` in `netdev->hw_features` to force TCP to calculate the check-sum in software.

For a example of setting up the hardware's feature-flags, take a look at
[**`lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/net/ethernet/intel/e1000e/netdev.c`**](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/net/ethernet/intel/e1000e/netdev.c#L6638).